# Updated theme and now WPBakery Tabs inserted in to PHP file don't show

Tags: php, wordpress

I inherited a site that needed a theme update (it was SEVERAL versions back; theme is Salient). The site uses WPBakery that came with the theme and uses a child theme that has a custom PHP template for a custom post type. I was able to update the theme for the most part....however, the custom post type doesn't display correctly. It uses an echo to insert WPBakery Tabbed Section shortcode. When WP Bakery is enabled, the tabs UL is empty; when WP Bakery is disabled, the page appears to work 90% correctly (but then the rest of the site is a mess without WPBakery enabled)

The problem code is

```
    echo do_shortcode(
        '[tabbed_section]'.
        '[tab title="Description" id="video-description-tab"]'.
        $clip_tab .
        $description_tab .
        '[/tab]' .
    
        get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "additional_tabs", true) . 
    
        '[tab title="Selected Clips" id="selected-clips-tab"]' .
        $extras_tab .
        '[/tab]' .
    
        '[tab title="Create a Clip" id="create-clip-tab"]' .
        $share_tab .
        '[/tab]' .
    
        '[/tabbed_section]'
    );
```

I can see the tab content when I inspect the page; And I can see the tabs UL; but it's empty

```
<ul class="wpb_tabs_nav ui-tabs-nav clearfix">
::before
::after
</ul>
```

The problem page is https://jannaw16.sg-host.com/a-megera-domada-fagundes-patricia-2008/ The Tabs should appear below the video area and above the content. Is there a different way to insert the WPBakery Shortcode that is more up-to-date that might make the code in the child theme incorrect?

Comment: That shortcode should work, **but** are you sure the variable data is actually getting passed to the echo? We need to see a little more code than what is provided.

Comment: The tab shortcode needed style="default" added with the newer version

Comment: Glad you got it figured out! Seems like they should update their code to pass the style argument by default instead.